# Webpack & Express hot reloading fails to update changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I'm trying to get my node server to hot reload with webpack but am not able to get it exactly right. Specifically, when i make a change, webpack rebuilds my bundle file, all everything looks like it's working, but then changes are not actually reflected. Quick example:

If I make a request to my route like this:

```
app.route('/reload').get((req,res) => res.send("hey!"))
```

I get back the message in the response. But then say i change the message to "testing", webpack outputs this:

```
Hash: bbc35083f3348a900df2
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 530ms
                               Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                           server.js    247 kB       0  [emitted]  main
0.2c807aa934f7a169bd08.hot-update.js   7.35 kB       0  [emitted]  main
2c807aa934f7a169bd08.hot-update.json  43 bytes          [emitted]  
[./api/modules/routeDefinitions.js] ./api/modules/routeDefinitions.js 6.97 kB {0} [built]
    + 91 hidden modules
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./api/modules/routeDefinitions.js
[HMR] Update applied.
```

But I still get the original message of "hey!" if i make another request to that route.

Webpack config, run with the command `webpack --config  ./config/webpack.config.api.js`:

```
const webpack           = require('webpack'),
      path              = require('path'),
      nodeExternals     = require('webpack-node-externals'),
      StartServerPlugin = require('start-server-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: [ 'webpack/hot/poll?1000', './api/index' ],
  watch: true,
  target: 'node',
  externals: [ nodeExternals({ whitelist: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000'] }) ],
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'] },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, use: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new StartServerPlugin('server.js'),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        BUILD_TARGET: JSON.stringify("server"),
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development")
      }
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '.build'),
    filename: 'server.js'
  }
}
```

And then my `app` should be reloaded from my `index.js` file which contains:

```
import http from 'http'
import app from './server'

const server  = http.createServer(app)

let currentApp = app

server.listen(3000)

// If the server should reload
if (module.hot) {
 module.hot.accept("./server", () => {

  // Remove the current server
  server.removeListener('request', currentApp)

  // Set a new instance
  server.on('request', app)

  // Store the new instance as the current instance
  currentApp = app

 })
}
```

Does anybody see anything wrong with this or know where i'm going wrong? I'm happy to post more code if you need it, just wanted to keep the post semi short lol. Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... Have you find out some fix?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this working? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi guys, no unfortunately I never ended up fixing this. My frustration with this workflow led me to use next.js which I pretty much use exclusively now for server/client side sites. I know this doesn't help lol